# Removing one child detaches all others in Entity Framework C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, cascading-deletes

I am trying to understand how cascading delete works. I have mentioned delete cascading to all entities however until I write code to loop through each child. So looping works fine so I am ok with it for now.

The problem I am getting is when I try to delete entity parent having multiple columns with same entity relation.

e.g. I have say working hours entity and then I have 7 columns for Monday to Sunday work hours.

My database looks like 
*Table DayHours*
DayId
OpeningTime
ClosingTime

*Table WorkingHours*
WorkingHoursId
MonId
TueId
WedId
ThusId
FriId
SatId
SunId

When I delete Workinghours entity I want all dayhours information to be deleted in child table however following code deletes only one entry and others remain orphan as after the first call to RemoveSelfAndChildProperties all others got detached from original parent so it gets child as null and never goes to delete other days...

```
protected void RemoveSelfAndChildProperties(DatabaseContext context, object parent)
        {
    DbEntityEntry entityEntry = context.Entry(parent);           
    foreach (PropertyInfo property in context.GetNavigationProperties(parent.GetType())){
        object child = property.GetValue(parent);
        if (child != null)
            this.RemoveSelfAndChildProperties(context, child);
        }
    }
    context.Set(parent.GetType()).Remove(entityEntry.Entity);
}
```

Comment: Please see  this [Missing EF Feature Workarounds: Cascade delete orphans](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2014/05/08/missing-ef-feature-workarounds-cascade-delete-orphans/) and this is another possible Workaround - [How I made EF work more like an object database](http://brockallen.com/2014/03/30/how-i-made-ef-work-more-like-an-object-database/).